# Given a generating set $S$ of a free $A$-module $M$, must $S$ contain an $A$-basis for $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Given a generating set $S$ of a free $A$-module $M$, must $S$ contain an $A$-basis for $M$?

I'm not sure if this is true or not. I've tried using a Zorn's Lemma argument which failed.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} = \langle 2,3\rangle$, isn't it?

Comment: Sometimes it's a good idea to interleave attempted proofs with searches for counterexamples.

Comment: And sometimes it is good to use the answer box for answers and the comment box for comments. ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Point taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a generating set for a free $A$-module $M$ need not contain a basis.

A simple counterexample is that $\{2,3\}$ is a generating set for the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}$. That can be generalised of course, whenever you have non-units $x_i \in A, \; 1 \leqslant i \leqslant k$ such that the ideal generated by the $x_i$ is the entire ring, you have a generating set that does not contain a basis. Of course, if $A$ is a field, then every generating set contains a basis.